# Try to refresh my view from a Thread but it give me an error

Tags: android, multithreading

This is my problem: I'm trying to add a element in my activity from a thread but it don't works.
This is my activity code :

```
public class AireDeJeu extends AppCompatActivity {
private final static int mObjectif = 100;
private int mProgression = 0;

private ImageView trou1, trou2, trou3, trou4, trou5, trou6, trou7, trou8, trou9, trou10, trou11, trou12;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.aire_de_jeu);


     trou1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou1); trou2= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou2); trou3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou3);
     trou4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou4); trou5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou5); trou6 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou6);
     trou7 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou7); trou8 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou8); trou9 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou9);
     trou10 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou10); trou11 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou11); trou12 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou12);

    trou1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });
/*
 *
 * I clear my 11 other onClickListener to be more clear.
 *
 */

        GenerateurPartie generateurPartie = new GenerateurPartie(niveau);

}

public void setPersonnage(int pId, int pRes){
    ImageView perso = (ImageView)findViewById(pId);
    perso.setImageResource(pRes);
}
```

}

It call my next class : "GenerateurPartie" where I start my Thread:

```
public class GenerateurPartie extends GenerateurPerso{

private int mNiveau;
public static int mAvancement = 0;
private int mDelai;
private Thread mThread;
private Perso mPerso;

private final HandlerDelai handlerDelai = new HandlerDelai();

protected static PlacementPerso mPlacementPerso = new PlacementPerso();

public GenerateurPartie(int pNiveau) {
    this.mNiveau = pNiveau;
    this.mDelai = 2500;

    mPlacementPerso.PlacementPerso();
   mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           try {
           int i = 0;
               while (mAvancement < 100) {

                   i += 1;

                   if (mAvancement >= 80)
                       mDelai = mDelai / 2;

                       Thread.sleep(mDelai);

                   handlerDelai.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           mPerso = GenerateurPerso(mNiveau, mAvancement);

                           mPlacementPerso.aPlacer(mPerso);
                       }
                   }, mDelai);
               }
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
   }});
    mThread.start();

    }
}
```

I don't show you my class "GenerateurPerso" to clarify my message and because it works great. The next one is my class "PlacementPerso", the logcat error become from it. It extends to my activity "AireDeJeu" :

```
public class PlacementPerso extends AireDeJeu{
private boolean trou1, trou2, trou3, trou4, trou5, trou6, trou7, trou8, trou9, trou10, trou11, trou12;

private Random r = new Random();
private int random, baseMax, baseMin;

public void PlacementPerso(){
    trou1 = true; trou2 = true; trou3 = true; trou4 = true; trou5 = true; trou6 = true; trou7 = true; trou8 = true; trou9 = true; trou10 = true; trou11 = true; trou12 = true;
    random = 1; baseMax = 12; baseMin = 1;
}

public void aPlacer(Perso pPerso){
    final int ressource = pPerso.getRessource();
    // ressource will be like : "R.drawable.img"

    random = r.nextInt((baseMax - baseMin) + 1) + baseMin;
    int trouId = 0;

    switch(random){
        case 1:
            if(trou1){
                trouId = R.id.trou1;
                trou1=false;
            }
            else {
                aPlacer(pPerso);
            }
            break;
        /**
         *
         * To clarify the code again I leave the 11 other case, they do the same thing, just the trouId value change.
         *
         */
    }

    final int pId = trouId;

    //This is my problem, it come from here
 super.setPersonnage(pId,ressource);
}
```

I already try a lot of solutions, I replace the `super.setPersonnage(pId,ressource);` by :

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           Log.d("Perso","Entrer dans runOnUiThread");
            ImageView perso = (ImageView)findViewById(pId);
            if(perso == null)
                Log.d("Perso","L'imageVew pour placer l'image est null !!!!!");
            else
                Log.d("Perso","L'imageVew pour placer l'image n'est pas null");
            perso.setImageResource(ressource);
        }

    });
```

But nothing works great. I tryed to add `setContentView(R.layout.aire_de_jeu)` before the findViewById but it didn't change anything.
(Other thing: when I try this code, the first Log appear but the second or the third don't appear ...)

To finish, this is my logcat:

```
10-07 11:30:47.758 31782-31782/com.dunomade.ecraseurdetaupe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.dunomade.ecraseurdetaupe, PID: 31782
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:72)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:29)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:191)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:173)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:511)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:183)
                                                                              at com.dunomade.ecraseurdetaupe.AireDeJeu.setPersonnage(AireDeJeu.java:136)
                                                                              at com.dunomade.ecraseurdetaupe.PlacementPerso.aPlacer(PlacementPerso.java:175)
                                                                              at com.dunomade.ecraseurdetaupe.GenerateurPartie$1$1.run(GenerateurPartie.java:56)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

It tells the error come from line: 136, here he come:

```
 public void setPersonnage(int pId, int pRes){
    ImageView perso = (ImageView)findViewById(pId); //Line 136
    perso.setImageResource(pRes);
}
```

I tryed to see if the problem came from my argument so I did:

```
 public void setPersonnage(int pId, int pRes){
    ImageView perso = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou1);
    perso.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
}
```

But the problem stay the same.

Maybe it's because I try to change the view in the thread ?!

I really hope someone can help me for this problem.
Maye my problem is my class "PlacementPerso" don't works in my thread, but I think it works on it.

Thank's advance =)

Comment: You have a NullPointerException and the logcat tells you that it is caused by a statement on line AireDeJeu.java:136.

Comment: The logcat I show you is when I'm running with the "runOnUiThread". I edit my message to show the true code who generate the logcat

Comment: Please take some time to format your stacktrace, before posting. That spaces looks ugly

Comment: `I edit my message to show the true code who generate the logcat `. ? You were asked to show the true code on line AireDeJeu.java:136.

Comment: Ok, I edit my message one more time, I show you the line you asked me. Thank's for your patience.

Comment: So on line 136 is `perso.setImageResource(pRes);` ? (why didnt you tell that?). So `perso==null`. Because findViewById() returned `null`. Do you see that now? You could have told us that right away. Read the log again. Are you using the right xml in setContentView? An xml that contains that ImageView?

Comment: Yes I call the right XML and the view is inside.
The problem is because I try to call `findViewById`outside `onCreate`. I'm trying to find a way to call it in my `handleMessage`.
Anyway I try to put my `handleMessage`in the `onCreate` but when I do this I can't create my handle in an other class.
I don't know what's the way I have to follow.

Comment: @greenapps: Or maybe you know a way to save the view after the initial `findViewById` in `onCreate` and to get it back after outside `onCreate`.
I don't know if I am clear, sorry for my english.

Comment: Put `ImageView perso;`. Above the onCreate() function. Use findViewById in onCreate to initialize `perso`. After that you can use `perso everywhere in your Activity.`

Comment: My god you have already done that with so many other ImageViews `private ImageView trou1, trou2, trou3, trou4, trou5, trou6, trou7, trou8, trou9, trou10, trou11, trou12;` Just add perso to it. Why did you ask it?
`

Comment: `final int pId = trouId;

    //This is my problem, it come from here
 super.setPersonnage(pId,ressource);`. Yes. Why didn't you tell in the first lines of your post? So `trouId` does not contain a valid id. Maybe it is stll 0. You are pretty much fidling around with `trouId.` in `aPlacer()`. Put log statements there to investigate.

Comment: Because I already try this way (the more logic) but it don't works !!! I'll be a new message to be clear and to show you where I am...
Thank's a lot for your help =)

Comment: Yes i'm sorry but I was on the wrong way to look what was the problem. I'm a beginner and I was lost.
I hope my new message will help you to understand the problem. Ask me questions if I forget something or if I'm not clear.
(I leave a lot of code to be more simple, maybe I leave to most...)

Answer (score 0):

In the way to be more clear, I'll try to show you what's happend:

I tryed a lot of possibilities but nothing works. But it help me to find where was really the problem. So I leave some code in the way to be more clear. I hope it'll help you to find a way with me to resolve it.

So this is my Activity:

```
public class AireDeJeu extends AppCompatActivity {

//I create all my ImageViews outside onCreate
public ImageView trou1, trou2, trou3, trou4, trou5, trou6, trou7, trou8, trou9, trou10, trou11, trou12;

//I make onCreate public to try to get the views later.
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.aire_de_jeu);

     //I get the view for all ImageView

     trou1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou1); trou2= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou2); trou3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou3);
     trou4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou4); trou5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou5); trou6 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou6);
     trou7 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou7); trou8 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou8); trou9 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou9);
     trou10 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou10); trou11 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou11); trou12 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trou12);
}
}
```

Here everything works great, nothing happend wrong. I can set a ressource like `trou6.setImageRessource(R.id.img);`and it works fine.

After this, I call a new Thread. It contain a random to choose the ImageView and a other random to choose the ressource, it work's every Xs (This is why I use `Thread`, for use `thread.sleep();`, to make a laps of time) and it create a message for my handler :

```
final private PlacementHandler placementHandler = new PlacementHandler();
final int KEY_PLACEMENT_PERSO = 1;

//ressource is like "R.drawable.img1", msg.arg2 is 0 because I don't need it, and viewTrou is the ImageView selected by the random (like trou1, or trou2...)
Message msg = placementHandler.obtainMessage(KEY_PLACEMENT_PERSO,ressource,0,viewTrou);
    placementHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

And to finish, this is where the probleme is, in my `handleMessage` :

```
public class PlacementHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        super.handleMessage(msg);

        //here is the problem, I get a NullPointerException
        ImageView perso = (ImageView)msg.obj;
        perso.setImageResource(msg.arg1);
    }
}
```

To be sure the problem don't come from my `msg.obj`or my `msg.arg1` I did:

```
public class PlacementHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        super.handleMessage(msg);

        //here is the problem again, my NullPointerException stop my app one more time
        trou1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
    }
}
```

This is what I don't understand: I create the `ImageViews` public outside `onCreate`, so I can access them in my `Handler`, but they are empty of view (because the view is created in `onCreate`). How can I get my `ImageView` WITH the view inside ?

Maybe the solution is to inflate the layout before to get a new `findViewById`, I also tryed this way but I don't know how to do...

I hope I'm clear and you understand what's my problem.
Sorry for my english.
Thank's a lot for helping.

PS: I already try to clear the project but nothing happend.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to make a new public class inside the onCreate to make `findViewById`on demande and to call this new class outside onCreate, like in my handleMessage. But I don't know how to do this. When I try this, I can only call this new function in onCreate...